# how to fix Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Tags: php, yii2

I try to make a delete function. but this happens,

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

This is my controller,

```
    $food=Makanan::findOne($id);
    unlink(Yii::$app->basePath . '/@web/upload/' . $food->img);
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    // $food->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

and this is my model,

```
return[
                [['nama','keterangan','stok','harga','img'],'required'],
                [['img'],'file','extensions'=>'jpg,jpeg,png'],
                [['stok','harga'],'integer'],
            ];
```

help please

Comment: It's difficult to say what is the reason for that based on the code sample you provided. Have you tried to debug it? And if `$this->findModel()` is fetching `Makanan` model why do you fetch it first with `findOne`?

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting Makanan model record by id, but there is no such attribute in your model rules